# PHP where exists Array not doing what it should

Tags: php, select, where-clause

Below code should only return table rows with the `status=0`, however it loads all of them instead:

```
$where_clouse='';

    get_header();

    $sql="SELECT P.`id`, P.`project_title`, P.`project_length`, P.`quality_level`, P.`writing_style`, 
            P.`article_purpose`,P.`author_voice`,P.`special_instruct`,P.`approve`,P.`status`,P.`date`,P.`budget`,P.client_id
            FROM `wp_project` AS P
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `wp_project` as A WHERE `status` = '0') ".$where_clouse."  ORDER BY P.`id`  ASC LIMIT $offset, $limit";

    $projects = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A)
```

Here is the code that pulls `$projects` further down and puts it correctly in an array, but not just the projects with `status=0`, all others as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php if(count($projects) > 0) { 
    foreach($projects as $project) {
        $title=$project['project_title'];
?>
```

I'd like to add that this `$sql` query had a few extra lines so I stripped it down, I don't exactly what this code is supposed to do, eg I don't understand this WHERE EXISTS.

Am I pulling everything twice here and as such it grabs all rows?

Comment: i wonder if your trouble comes from `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 'wp_project' as A WHERE 'status' = '0')` -- you might want to add more clause to refer filter how existence should be checked, [look at these example], on the first example for instance defines whether given store type exists in the city or not. if you want to filter out everything with `not status = 0` just use `WHERE`.. well, without your table structure and what do you want to retrieve from the table as a clue.. it'd be hard to guess.

Comment: Thank you, I have honestly no clue about the basic concepts, just have a lot of code and with copy/pasting I accomplished a lot but sometimes I get stuck. Makes sense there's no need to use EXISTS as I already know it exists, earlier it pulled the data from two tables, eg projects and articles so it was all weaven together. Anyway, the poster below provided the solution by putting P. in front of status and that fixed it instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 $sql="SELECT P.`id`, P.`project_title`, P.`project_length`, P.`quality_level`, P.`writing_style`, 
            P.`article_purpose`,P.`author_voice`,P.`special_instruct`,P.`approve`,P.`status`,P.`date`,P.`budget`,P.client_id
            FROM `wp_project` AS P
            WHERE P.status = 0 ". $where_clouse ."  ORDER BY P.`id`  ASC LIMIT $offset, $limit";
```

btw I think the backticks are not necessary.

Comment: The P. did the job indeed, I didn't use your code but put just the P. in front of status and that fixed the problem right away. Previously the WHERE EXIST line pulled the data from a different table, but I merged both tables into one and then the problems started so that's why it's such a complicated rule vs your version, it already look kind of silly to me to pull everything twice. Thanks for your answer, I will try that now as it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: Had to change it a tiny bit, P.`status` = '0' putting those quotes and the other odd symbols to make it work. Much cleaner now, thanks a lot!